# keeps adding space at bottom of table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having an issue with an options and answers feature I have. If I select an options which contains an output of some many buttons e.g If I choose option 20, it will display 20 buttons, the problem I am getting  is that at the bottom of the table column, the space drops down a little bit. It only does it when an option is changed and then the space remains throughout. My question is simply how can I stop the space at the bottom of the table column to increase when an option changes?

The table column which is the issue is known as `extratd` and inside this table column is a nested table known as answer. I want `extratd` to be `vertical-align:top;` as it is now.

Below is the HTML/jquery code where it contains the table row, the table and the code where it contains the letter buttons display:

```
var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
var $td = $("<td width='16%' class='extratd'>");
var $answer = $("<table class='answer'><tbody><tr><td class='ans'>3. Answer:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
var $this, i = 0,
    $row, $cell;
$('#optionAndAnswer .answers').each(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    if (i % 6 == 0) {
        $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
        $cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);
    }
    var $newBtn = $(("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this, " + gQuestionIndex + ");' />").replace('%s', $this.is(':visible') ? 'inline-block' : 'none')).attr('name', "value[" + gQuestionIndex + "][]").attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class')).attr('id', $this.attr('id') + 'Row');
    $newBtn.appendTo($cell);
    i++;
});
var $this = $(this);
var $BtnsClass = '';
$row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
$cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);
if ($questionType == 'True or False' || $questionType == 'Yes or No') {
    $BtnsClass = $("<input class='allBtnsRow btnsAll' type='button' style='display: none;' value='Select All Answers' onClick='selectAll(this);' /><input class='allRemoveBtnsRow btnsRemove' type='button' style='display: none;' value='Remove All Answers' onClick='removeAll(this);' />");
} else {
    $BtnsClass = $("<input class='allBtnsRow btnsAll' type='button' value='Select All Answers' onClick='selectAll(this);' /><br/><input class='allRemoveBtnsRow btnsRemove' type='button' value='Remove All Answers' onClick='removeAll(this);' />");
}
$BtnsClass.appendTo($cell);
$tr.append($td);
$td.append($answer);
$tbody.append($tr);
```

Below is the CSS for the `extratd` and `answer`:

```
.extratd{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    vertical-align:top; 
    padding-top:1em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;

}

.answer{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I have found out that the code that is causing this problem is this:

```
  //THE ISSUE IS HERE

var _x = $(e.currentTarget);
var _y = _x.closest('td.extratd');
var _z = _y.prev();

$('textarea', _z).css('height', '').height(_z.innerHeight());

//ISSUE ABOVE
```

Now what the code above does is allow the textarea within the `Question` column to fill the whole table cell when ever the textarea is appended or if the option changes. So I need the code above but what the code above also does is create an unnecessary space at the bottom of the table row so I need help to sort out the unwanted space.

I have a jsfiddle here which you can use to see what is happening and it also includes the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/aND4g/61/

Please follow steps below in order to use fiddle:

1. When you open fiddle, on top type in a content in the question textarea and then click on `Open Grid` and select button `3` or `4`.
2. When you have done step 1 then click on the `Add Question` button to append the above details into the table below
3. Now WITHIN THE APPENDED ROW, click on the `Open Grid` and select the other option from what you first chosen. You will see that it creates an unwanted space at the bottom of the table row

Comment: Any way you could throw this quickly into a jsfiddle so we can visually see the problem ?

Comment: @RyanBeaulieu if you don't mind waiting I will put it into a fiddle

Comment: @RyanBeaulieu Gonna have to give me more time on fiddle, I realised that the code I have for fiddle is not producing the space if I just have this table column, meaning something else could be causing the extra space

Comment: Not a problem. Hey, maybe putting your code in a fiddle will help you see your error.

Comment: @RyanBeaulieu Ok I know what is causing the issue, just need help with the fix, it is the column next the options and answers column which is `Question` column which is causing the issue, if I don't have this column, then no space is added at bottom, but with this column it creates a space when the option changes. I will get the fiddle up, just going to include his code and remove unwanted code, give me 10-15 mins and it will be up

Comment: @RyanBeaulieu Please look at update where I included info and jsfiddle

Comment: One problem I am seeing right away is that you have two tables nested inside one another.

Comment: @RyanBeaulieu Yes I do, I was trying to dispaly the option type, number of answers and answers above one another, shall I do it another way? if so just change it in fiddle. If it isn't much of a problem then leave the nested table

Comment: I'm at work right now but when I get a second to really look at this I'll find the error for you.

Comment: @RyanBeaulieu That is cool, no rush, Im working on other things anyway so I can get on with them being getting back into this

Answer (score 0):

Is it maybe something to do with your padding-bottom value of 1em?  Maybe try tweaking or removing that and it might fix it.  A jsFiddle would definitely help to picture the problem though.

Comment: Hi, I tried removing the padding beforehand and that did not cause the problem. when the table row appears it starts of with a padding bottom of 1em but then when I change an option, then it adds extra space. I will get a fiddle up, give me 10 mins

Comment: Gonna have to give me more time on fiddle, I realised that the code I have for fiddle is not producing the space if I just have this table column, meaning something else could be causing the extra space

Comment: Ok I know what is causing the issue, just need help with the fix, it is the column next the options and answers column which is `Question` column which is causing the issue, if I don't have this column, then no space is added at bottom, but with this column it creates a space when the option changes. I will get the fiddle up, just going to include his code and remove unwanted code, give me 10-15 mins and it will be up